# mongodb: Database not showing up in show dbs after data is inserted

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am following a YouTube tutorial from Jose Annunziato. I created my `server.js` and did all the required settings and configurations for my database connection. Now when I am posting something from the form to the server: it shows the data is sent to the server successfully but when I go to the mongo console to verify if the data is received and database is created or not. I run `db` it says test I run `show dbs` and there I can't see my new Database. I am not sure what the actual problem is because I did everything Jose said in the tutorial.

*Server.js*

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/blogfall2016');

var PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    body: String,
    tag: {type: String, enum:['POLITICS', 'ECONOMY', 'EDUCATION']},
    posted: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
});

var PostModel = mongoose.model('PostModel', PostSchema)
// GET /style.css etc
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post("/api/blogpost", CreatePost);

function CreatePost(req, res) {
    var post = req.body;
    console.log(post);
    PostModel.create(post);
    res.json(post);

}


app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your schema and data you want to insert are matched then it should work.

**Try below code. instead of**  `PostModel.create(post);`

```
    var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/nnnnnn', function (err) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log('connection successful');
    } else {
        console.log(err)
    }
});

var PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    body: String,
    tag: { type: String, enum: ['POLITICS', 'ECONOMY', 'EDUCATION'] },
    posted: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

var PostModel = mongoose.model('PostModel', PostSchema)
// GET /style.css etc
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post("/api/blogpost", CreatePost);

function CreatePost(req, res) {
    var post = req.body;
    console.log(post);
    // static data
    var post = {
        title: 'asdfasdf',
        body: 'asdfasdfasdfasdf',
        tag: 'POLITICS',
        posted: new Date()
    }
    var postModel = new PostModel(post);

    postModel.save(function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error', err);
        } else {
            console.log('data inserted');
        }
    });


    res.json(post);

}


app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: this error is due to schema mismatch. Check whether your data i.e post and schema should match. And console your post and reply what are saving.

Comment: you can see the schema in my questions and the data I am posting is title and body only. 

 <input ng-model="post.title" class="form-control" placeholder="title"/>
    <textarea ng-model="post.body" class="form-control" placeholder="body"></textarea>
    <button ng-click="createPost(post)" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">submit</button>

Comment: I had edited your code and its working fine on my system with static data.

Comment: can you please give  console.log(post);

Comment: {title: "asdasdasdas", body: "asdasdasdas"}

Comment: {"title":"asdfasdf","body":"asdfasdfasdfasdf","tag":"POLITICS","posted":"2017-08-10T13:51:47.704Z"}

Comment: I think its working but can you explain whats wrong with my code and why is it not working

Comment: As per your first snapshot post variable data and schema was a mismatch. Due to that exception occurs as shown in snapshot.

Comment: I mean the code I pasted in the question. why is that not valid? because in the tutorial author said only the required field should be  not null otherwise rest of the fields can be left empty.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of below line

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/blogfall2016');
```

Try this one to make sure that database created successfully first,
then do your operation

```
mongoose.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Database created!");
  db.close();
});
```

Comment: what does url mean here?

Comment: var url  =  'mongodb://localhost/blogfall2016';

Comment: here is the result

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/mongoose -- try this link to know how to use mongoose